# Test code with out writing server side code

Tags: android

I am writing an android app that involves file upload. Is there any way I can check the code for potential out of memory error with out actually writing the server side code? If yes,please explain. The code is provided below :-

```
private void sendToRemoteServer(){
         Socket client;
         FileInputStream fileInputStream;
         BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
         OutputStream outputStream;

         try{
             client                 =   new Socket("10.0.2.2",444);
             byte[] myByteArray     =   new byte[(int)mFile.length()];
             fileInputStream        =   new FileInputStream(mFile);
             bufferedInputStream    =   new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

             bufferedInputStream.read(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.length); //read the file

             outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

             outputStream.write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.length); //write file to the output stream byte by byte
             outputStream.flush();
             bufferedInputStream.close();
             outputStream.close();
             client.close();
         }catch(UnknownHostException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: the error is likely to happen here `new byte[(int)mFile.length()];`. you can test this part without the socket.

Comment: Okey,I get your point :), thanks for the insight :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to copy the whole file at once to your byte array.

This is better and should never cause memory issues (you will never use more than 8 kB of memory) :

```
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[8192];
int len;
...
while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(mByteArray, 0, len)) != -1)
    outputStream.write(mByteArray, 0, len);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

It's called dependency injection : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Create this interface

```
public interface ISocket{
    void close():
    OutputStream getOutputStream();
}
```

And make sure your socket class herits from it.

Your constructor becomes

```
private void sendToRemoteServer(){
     ISocket client;
```

When you want to test locally, just pass as argument any implementation of ISocket that do whatever you want with the close method and the getOutputStream methods.